# osx netstat show listen socket on port but lsof don't

Tags: mac-osx

Inside OSX(10.8.3) netstat show listen socket on port but lsof don't:

```
> iMac:callsfreecalls-apple alex$ lsof -Pnl +M -i4|grep 5060
> iMac:callsfreecalls-apple alex$ sudo netstat -lntp udp|grep 5060
> Password: udp4   18546      0  *.5060                 *.*
```

please advice.

sudo isn't help:

```
> server:sites alex$  
> server:sites alex$ ssh 192.168.0.58 Password: Last
> login: Tue Jun  4 10:26:04 2013 
> iMac:~ alex$ sudo lsof -Pnl +M -i4 |
> grep 5060 Password: 
> iMac:~ alex$ netstat -lntp udp | grep 5060 udp4  
> 18546      0  *.5060                 *.*                              
> iMac:~ alex$
```

Answer (score 2):

You need `sudo` with `lsof` to see other users' processes (OTOH you *don't* need `sudo` with `netstat`):

```
$ netstat -lntp udp | grep 5353
udp6       0      0  *.5353                                        *.*                                                      
udp4       0      0  *.5353                 *.*                               
$ lsof -Pnl +M -i4 | grep 5353    # Won't work
$ sudo lsof -Pnl +M -i4 | grep 5353    # Will work
mDNSRespo 94183       65    8u  IPv4 0xca78f18f22d6d11b      0t0  UDP *:5353
```

Comment: no, it not help

Comment: `-lntp` doesn't work on Darwin's netstat.